# Calculate dynamically width of elements?

Tags: angular

I have array of elements that I want to display, and I want to calculate every element's width dynamically, based on the number of elements.

Any suggestion?

```
  <span class="years" [style.width.%]="65%/data.length"
        *ngFor="let year of data">{{year.displayName |translate}}</span>
```

Comment: Do you need to solution to be js, or is there any reason you don't want to just use css (either flex box or selectors?)

Comment: i cannot use flexbox becuase of structure of html... i dont have "parent" element that will keep all of that elements.

Comment: Oh, so you're not looping over each element to display, but instead have a single element that you want to somehow represent length (like a bar chart?).

Comment: And is the width relative to a flexible parent element, or something you know the width of (e.g. a fixed-width element, page width etc.)? I've given a possible solution below, but if that doesn't work perhaps putting together a quick stackblitz/codepen/jsfiddle or whatever would make it easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy option might be to put a function inline in your template and use that to calculate the width

*component.html*

```
 <span class="years" [style.width]="calculateWidth(data.length)"
        *ngFor="let year of data">{{year.displayName |translate}}</span>
```

*component.ts*

```
calculateWidth(length){
  return 65/length+'%'
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid the template calculating on every render it would probably be better to just calculate when the data first comes in. E.g. keep a variable called `spanWidth` or similar, and assign a value on data received (if passed from parent using a [setter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) or [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges))